# How to get table names with specific prefix using Yii2 db schema?

Tags: php, database, schema, yii2

I develop an app using Yii2 platform and sql server database.

In database, I have some tables with prefix name 'M_' and some others with 'T_' to separate which tables used for backend/master and frontend.

I meant to get the tables name only the tables with prefix 'M_' using Yii2 class Schema (yii\db\schema).

my recently code for sure will return all the tables name

```
$db_connection = Yii::$app->db;
$dbSchema = $db_connection->schema;
$tables = $dbSchema->getTableNames();
foreach($tables as $tbl){
    //echo $tbl;
}
```

I maybe can use the strpos function to get tables name i need.

But any of you have an better way/idea to get through this?

Comment: If you want static solution then you can use: `foreach($tables as $tbl){
    if($tbl == "_M")echo $tbl;
}`

Comment: And if you want to do this using db/schema then you have to manually override `getTableNames()` function or you can use `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code should give you the array you want

```
$tableNames = array_filter($tables, function($var) {
        return substr($var, 0, 2) == 'M_';
});
```

reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php